# Improve PHP code to store values of an array in a database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have 2 multidimensional arrays and I want to insert its values into a database table.

```
Array
(
    [menu_categorie] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Breakfast
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Desert
                )

        )

    [menu_meal_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Salade
                        )

                    [price] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                        )

                    [description] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Lorem
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Chocolate
                        )

                    [price] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                        )

                    [description] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Lorem
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Currently, the values within $_POST['menu_meal_name'] are not being saved, and only the latest value of $menu_categorie is being stored, disregarding multiple entries. How can I enhance my code to address these issues?

```
$menu_categorie = isset($_POST['menu_categorie']) ? map_deep( $_POST['menu_categorie'], 'sanitize_text_field' ) : array();
$menu_meal_name = isset($_POST['menu_meal_name']) ? map_deep( $_POST['menu_meal_name'], 'sanitize_text_field' ) : array();

global $wpdb;       
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "restaurant"; 



        // Start loop 
        if (!empty($menu_categorie) || !empty($menu_meal_name)) {
            
            foreach ($menu_categorie as $key => $categorie_data) {
                $categorie_name = isset($categorie_data['name']) ? $categorie_data['name'] : '';

                if ($categorie_name) {
                    
                    $meals = isset($menu_meal_name[$key]) ? $menu_meal_name[$key] : array();

                    foreach ($meals as $meal) {
                        $meal_name = isset($meal['name']) ? $meal['name'] : '';
                        $price = isset($meal['price']) ? floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $meal['price'])) : 0;
                        $description = isset($meal['description']) ? $meal['description'] : '';

                        if (!empty($categorie_name) || !empty($meal_name)) {
                            $current_time = current_time('mysql');
                            $data_to_insert = array(
                                'post_id' => $post_id,
                                'post_title' => get_the_title($post_id),
                                'categorie' => $categorie_name,
                                'meal_name' => $meal_name,
                                'price' => $price,
                                'pp' => 0,
                                'description' => $description,
                            );

                            $existing = $wpdb->get_row(
                                $wpdb->prepare(
                                    "SELECT id FROM {$table_name} WHERE post_id = %d AND meal_name = %s",
                                    absint($post_id),
                                    $meal_name
                                )
                            );

                            if ($existing) {
                                $data_to_insert['aangepast_op'] = $current_time;
                                $wpdb->update(
                                    $table_name,
                                    $data_to_insert,
                                   array('id' => $existing->id)
                                );
                            } else {
                                $data_to_insert['aangemaakt_op'] = $current_time;
                                $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Does the array `menu_categorie` will just have a nested key-pair array of `name => 'some item'`? If so then do you need this line `$categorie_name = isset($categorie_data['name']) ? $categorie_data['name'] : '';`? Also just before sql transaction why are you checking the `categorie_name` again`!empty($categorie_name)`, you arlready checking it `if ($categorie_name)`? Is this correct `$meal['name']` way to access when you have a given index under it like `[0] => Salade`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu_categorie = isset($_POST['menu_categorie']) ? map_deep($_POST['menu_categorie'], 'sanitize_text_field') : array();
$menu_meal_name = isset($_POST['menu_meal_name']) ? map_deep($_POST['menu_meal_name'], 'sanitize_text_field') : array();

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "restaurant";

if (!empty($menu_categorie) || !empty($menu_meal_name)) {
    foreach ($menu_categorie as $cat_key => $categorie_data) {
        $categorie_name = isset($categorie_data['name']) ? $categorie_data['name'] : '';

        if (!empty($categorie_name)) {
            // Yemekler için dizi kontrolü ve döngü
            if (isset($menu_meal_name[$cat_key])) {
                foreach ($menu_meal_name[$cat_key] as $meal_key => $meal_data) {
                    // Yemek ismi, fiyat ve açıklama için ayrı ayrı kontrol
                    $meal_name = isset($meal_data['name'][0]) ? $meal_data['name'][0] : '';
                    $price = isset($meal_data['price'][0]) ? floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $meal_data['price'][0])) : 0;
                    $description = isset($meal_data['description'][0]) ? $meal_data['description'][0] : '';

                    if (!empty($meal_name)) {
                        $current_time = current_time('mysql');
                        $data_to_insert = array(
                            'post_id' => $post_id,
                            'post_title' => get_the_title($post_id),
                            'categorie' => $categorie_name,
                            'meal_name' => $meal_name,
                            'price' => $price,
                            'pp' => 0,
                            'description' => $description,
                        );

                        // Veritabanında mevcut olup olmadığını kontrol et
                        $existing = $wpdb->get_row(
                            $wpdb->prepare(
                                "SELECT id FROM {$table_name} WHERE post_id = %d AND meal_name = %s",
                                absint($post_id),
                                $meal_name
                            )
                        );

                        // Mevcutsa güncelle, değilse ekle
                        if ($existing) {
                            $data_to_insert['aangepast_op'] = $current_time;
                            $wpdb->update(
                                $table_name,
                                $data_to_insert,
                                array('id' => $existing->id)
                            );
                        } else {
                            $data_to_insert['aangemaakt_op'] = $current_time;
                            $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you try it this way?

Sorry google translate :)

Comment: Avoid code-only answers. Please explain what you've changed, and why it's expected to correct the issue.